# Open and short test for 2 ground pin

Tags: test, open-drain

If a device has two ground pins. Using the normal open and short test will not tell if one ground pin is open and the other is good. How to detect this kind of situation?

Thanks.

Comment: So what about your situation is stopping you from a doing a continuity test between the two ground pins?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Assume the IC first three pins are ground pins (and are shorted internally)
- The PCB pads are ground pads (green ones).
- failing to soldering to pin number one **cannot** be detected with simple continuity tests.

  ---

Ideas to find out whether particular pin is connected or not to the PCB track:

[Find short location on PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/find-short-location-on-pcb)